# Trigonometry in PHP (Inverse Sine)

Tags: php, math, trigonometry

I didn't pay as much attention as I should have in math class, don't shoot me.

Anyway... I'm trying to calculate a degree of rotation. I have my hypotenuse & opposite lengths (it is a right triangle).

So I'm guessing the equation should look like:

```
$radians = sin-1 ($opposite/$hypotenuse);
```

I see a sine function (`sin`) but I don't see an inverse sine function (i.e. sin-1).

Do I just `pow(sin($opposite/$hypotenuse),-1)` it, or so I have my trig all confused?

Answer (score 2):

Use [asin](http://php.net/asin) (for `arcsine`, another name of sin<sup>-1</sup>).

And don't confuse the `-1` here with exponents! It's just an unfortunate syntax. Inverse functions have nothing to do with exponentials. That's why some people prefer to use the name `arcsin` instead of sin<sup>-1</sup>.